# Lebesgue measure of an image of a continuous function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

There is given a function $f\colon\mathbb  R\to\mathbb R$ that is $C^1$ and set $K$ so that $K = \{\,x\mid f'(x)=0\,\}$. How to prove that image of set $K$ is of measure $0$ (one-dimension Lebesgue measure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of [Sard's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sard%27s_theorem), so you might want to look at a proof, for example [here](http://math.uchicago.edu/~amwright/Sard.pdf)